# How to extract the values from a external PHP contents that outputs JSON using Ajax?

Tags: php, html, json, ajax

I wrote the PHP file that returns my server's current time and date
http://cgbp.org/date.php with code

```
<?php 
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  $timezone = date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Manila");
  $time = date("H:i:s A");
  $date = date("m-d-Y");    

  $datecontents = array(
    "time" => $time,
    "date" => $date
  );    

  echo json_encode($datecontents);

  $fp = fopen('dates.json', 'w');
  fwrite($fp, json_encode($datecontents));
  fclose($fp);
?>
```

How do I get the time and date values via Ajax request and display them in div?
Below is current that isn't working.

```
$.ajax({
dataType: 'json',
url: 'http://cgbp.org/date.php',
success: function (result) {
    var InternetDate = new Date(result.date);
    var monthNames = [
                      "January", "February", "March",
                      "April", "May", "June", "July",
                      "August", "September", "October",
                      "November", "December"
                      ];

    var weekday = new Array(7);
    weekday[0]=  "Sunday";
    weekday[1] = "Monday";
    weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
    weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
    weekday[4] = "Thursday";
    weekday[5] = "Friday";
    weekday[6] = "Saturday";

    var dayofweek = weekday[InternetDate.getDay()]; 
    var day = InternetDate.getDate();
    var monthIndex = monthNames[InternetDate.getMonth()];
    var year = InternetDate.getFullYear();

    //document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = dayofweek +', '+ monthIndex +' '+ day +', '+ year;
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = result.datecontents;
    document.getElementById('curdate').value = result.date;
}});
```

Comment: What is the result you get? Incorrect result, or an error message?

Answer (score 0):

`result.datecontents` is not set, use the commented line instead.